# Solving Recurrence Relation

Tags: algorithm, recurrence

I am learning recurence relation now. I know that;

```
t(n) = t(n/2) + t(n/5) + n is t(n) = theta n
```

What about;

```
t(n) = t(n/2) + t(n/5) + nlogn
t(n) = t(n/2) + t(n/5) + logn
t(n) = t(n/2) + t(n/5) + n^2
t(n) = t(n/2) + t(n/5) + n^1/2
```

I have no idea to solve them.

Comment: Isn't this better suited on [cstheory](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com)?

Comment: i solved 3rd for you.if it is helpful accept and upvote it

Answer (score 0):

I am solving one for you,

```
t(n) = t(n/2) + t(n/5) + n^2<br>Using recurrence tree<br>

          (n)
      /        \
    (n/2)       (n/5)---->         (n/2)^2+(n/5)^2=(29/100)*n^2
   /    \         /      \ 
(n/2^2)  (n/10)  (n/10)  (n/5^2)------>(n/4)^2+(n/10)^2+(n/10)^2+(n/25)^2=(29/100)^2*n^2
|         |               |
|         |               |  
|         |               |
```

this will end when n/5^k will be equal to 1
 so `n/5^k=1  =>n=5^k => k=log(n) having base 5`
at k level some of all terms

**n^2(29/100+(29/100)^2+ . . . +(29/100)^k)**
this is GP so its sum is

```
n^2 * [1-(29/100)^log(n)]/[1-29/100]
```

[1-(29/100)^log(n)]/[1-29/100] this term will be less than 1 so can be neglected so complexity will be **n^2**